# How to create JSON from C# dictionary similar to PHP

Tags: c#, php, json, facebook-graph-api, tagging

PHP code to make an array

```
$tag = array(
'tag_uid' => 1234,
'x' => 0,
'y' => 0
);

$tags[] = $tag;
```

OUTPUT: `{"x":"0","y":"0","tag_uid":"1234"}`

I want to make this as JSON array in C# with the same OUTPUT for that I need help, I can't figure out which array it will be? a simple array or what.
I have tag_uid which i can pass to function and i am using JSON.NET I don't know what should i need to write in the JsonArry function but I have tried to following

```
 public JsonArray CreatePhotoTag(string userId)
        {
            Dictionary<string, object> tagParameters = new Dictionary<string, object>();
            tagParameters.Add("x", "0");
            tagParameters.Add("y", "0");
            tagParameters.Add("tag_uid", userId);
            JsonArray tagsarray = ???

            return tagsarray ;
        }
```

Please help me

Comment: using System.Web.Script.Serialization;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend switching to [ServiceStack.NET Text](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text). It is incredibly fast compared to JSON.NET.

You can serialize it like this:

*ServiceStack.NET*

```
var jsonSerializer = new JsonSerializer<Dictionary<String, Object>>();
var tagsArray = jsonSerializer.SerializeToString(tagParameters);
```

If you really want to use JSON.NET

*JSON.NET*

```
var tagsArray = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(tagParameters, Formatting.Indented);
```

Comment: Run this http://code.google.com/p/servicestack/source/browse/trunk/Common/Northwind.Benchmarks/Northwind.Benchmarks/Serialization/SerializationTestBase.cs?r=1226 and you'll see why I can't recommend the built-in serializers.

Comment: Sorry for late accepting the answer, seems like I was far away from SOF :D